# Why does using Update query give me different result instead of updating data in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to update data in textbox and this error show up. Is it incorrect query?

[image]

```
  Try
        Dim Str = "UPDATE userinfo SET firstname='" & TextBox1.Text.ToUpper & "',lastname='" & TextBox3.Text.ToUpper & "'," &
         "WHERE id='" & Label15.Text
        connection.Open()
        Dim mysc2 As New MySqlCommand(Str, connection)
        mysc2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("User successfully updated!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        connection.Close()
        Me.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        connection.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: It's extremely frustrating when people get an error message telling them that they have an error in their SQL code and then post a question about it without even showing that SQL code. Usually it's because they haven't even looked at that SQL code themselves, which means that they are asking for help without bothering to try for themselves first. The issue is not the VB code that constructs the SQL code. It is the SQL code itself so use your eyes to look at the SQL code itself. If you do that then the issue should be obvious and it shows why building SQL code this way is bad.

Comment: And also learn to use parameterised queries because there's a reasonable chance that would solve the problem with no further effort needed. Almost any ado.net tutorial would show you the right way to write your queries

Comment: Also, try removing the last comma before the WHERE

Comment: And if you decide against parametrised queries as suggested by ADyson (e.g. for easier debugging with tools like SQL Server Profiler) then at least double the apostrophes. If some user enters `'; SELECT '` all first names of the whole table are cleared.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, it not only less then ideal to try and concat all those things together, but as you can see it is ALSO really easy to mess up the sql string.

So, your sql looks wrong. It should be this:

```
Dim Str as string
Str = "UPDATE userinfo SET firstname = '" & TextBox1.Text.ToUpper & "'," & _
      "lastname = '" & TextBox3.Text.ToUpper & "'" & _
      " WHERE id= " & Label15.Text
```

Now of course, we don't know if "ID" is a string, or a number type. And if it is a number, then you do NOT surround the Lable15.Text value with single quotes.  And you had a extra "," after the list textbox 3 in your sql.

But, as noted, the suggestion here is to use parameters. While this is a bit wee extra code, such code is LESS prone to concatenation errors, is easier to read, and in fact easier to write.  (you can hit ctrl-d in the code editor to duplicate the line you are on!!!).

and of course, using parameters ALSO gives you AUTOMATIC data typing. So you don't have to worry or think about those extra parameters. And not only do numbers have no single quotes around them, date delimiters can even be more of a challenge.

Along without the messy concatenation?
Along without the data type issue (quotes or not????)
We ALSO get protection from SQL injection.

So, we getting a real nice truckload of bonus features. I have ALWAYS lamented that many suggest to use parameters, but then don't point out the benefits (beyond that of sql injection).

So you might wind up with a extra line or two of code, but that code is LESS error prone, and in most cases will be easier to read, but ALSO MUCH more able to allow you to add more parameters - all without messy string concatenations.

So, our code can be this:

```
Dim Str As String

Str = "UPDATE userinfo SET firstname = @firstName, lastname = @lastname WHERE id = @id"

Using cmdSQL As New MySqlCommand(Str, connection)

    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@lastname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Label15.Text

    cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
    cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Using
```

Some interesting things to note:
First: it really nice to read, right?
Second: Easy to code.

When I typed in this:

```
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
```

While on above, I hit ctrl-d two times. that duplicated the above line.

So now, I just "cursor" up/down into the parameter value area almost like editing a column in Excel. (I did not HAVE to type those extra lines - but just edit the values and change the textbox/label values.

And BETTER is while typing in that code, I can EASY see, and read, view the nice sql line right above in code - so I just read off the parameters as I type, and edit the two additonal parameters rows. So, in fact, I actually wind up typing LESS then your posted code. And with the nice sql text in view - I have a LOWER brain work load - I don't have to remember the parameters - I just read them!

Next up:

SQL server does not care about upper vs lower case - so you don't need to worry about upper and lower - they will match regardless.

More next up:
By wrapping the whole deal inside of a using, then we don't have to close the connection - this is correctly handled by the using block (it cleans up for you).

More more next up:

And because we don't use string concatenation for the values, and DO NOT have to worry about quotes or not, and also get sql injection protection?
We ALSO get STRONG data typing.

In other words, the values from the controls are CAST to the correct data types required by sql server. I mean, often you can munge in a number with quotes as a string - sql server might work, might not! - but this way, automatic taking care of the quotes (or no quotes for numbers) is done for you!

so the updated original sql string should work, but give the parameters a try, and while the using block is a extra line of code, we don't have to close the connection, so we get back that 1 line of code!

The major goal here is it not that you must do this, or do that! Often when starting out, such advice is not all that helpful. Saying don't do that? Geesh - what kind of help is that.

In above, I not only said to use parameters, but I ALSO made a long and impassioned case as to why they are better.

The strong data typing is really nice, and protection from SQL injection is in fact a bonus feature here!

The real gold here is that we wound up with not a lot of code, and code that is easier to maintain, easier to read, and even MORE so if we decide in the future to add some more text boxes etc. on the form.

I mean, lets say you have 4 or 5 text boxes. Can you imagine then how absolute difficult that long huge concatenated string will be to edit, look at, and more so try to debug errors!

So must you use parameters? no, you don't have to, but once you try the above?
You adopt the above because the code is less mental effort and work on your part - and that's really what great code is all about.

I not that great of a coder, and thus your long string sql is too hard for me, and too great of a effort. Only those really good coders can figure out that mess. For me, you have to think as me as a one cell creature - limited brain power. The same goes for great pool players. They actually don't make the hard and difficult shots - they set themselves up in such a way that they never have to make those hard shots, or in this case read and maintain difficult and complex code.

Your code can work - but it is beyond my pay grade and ability to read and maintain such code!

Good luck!